# Jump directly to certain page using UIPageViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using UIPageViewController to swipe around images. There are set of small images in view controller and then I segue to another view controller that shows only the bigger image. I have created a page view controller with scroll view and it works fine but it always starts from the first image. Let's say the first controller has five small images, and let's say if user taps on the third image to see it in a bigger size, the segue to the second controller showing the bigger image is done successfully and the current page is also set to 3 but the image is the first image. When I'm segueing to this second controller, I pass on the array containing image urls and based on the index clicked on the first view the current page is set but the image is the first image in the array.

[image]

[image]

How can I fix this problem? Below is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ImageViewerViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    @IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!

    var seguedAlbumImagePathArray=[]
    var seguedCurrentImageIndex: Int?


    var totalPages: Int = 0

    //let sampleBGColors: Array<UIColor> = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.magentaColor(), UIColor.orangeColor()]

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        totalPages = seguedAlbumImagePathArray.count
        view.bringSubviewToFront(pageControl)
    }


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        configureScrollView()
        configurePageControl()
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    }


    // MARK: Custom method implementation

    func configureScrollView() {
        // Enable paging.
        scrollView.pagingEnabled = true

        // Set the following flag values.
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.scrollsToTop = false

        // Set the scrollview content size.
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * CGFloat(totalPages), scrollView.frame.size.height)

        // Set self as the delegate of the scrollview.
        scrollView.delegate = self

        // Load the ImageView view from the ImageView.xib file and configure it properly.
        for i in 0 ..< totalPages {
            // Load the ImageView view.
            let imageView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ImageView", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            // Set its frame and the background color.
            imageView.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(i) * scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)
            //imageView.backgroundColor = sampleBGColors[i]

            // Set the proper message to the test view's label.
            let label = imageView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
            label.text = "\(i + 1)/\(totalPages)"

            // Set the proper message to the test view's label.
            let imagev = imageView.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
            view.sendSubviewToBack(imagev)

            if let imageData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(seguedAlbumImagePathArray[i] as! String),
                let imageToDisplay = UIImage(data: imageData as! NSData) {
                imagev.image = imageToDisplay
                view.sendSubviewToBack(imagev)
            }
            else {
                ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(seguedAlbumImagePathArray[i] as! String, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in
                    imagev.image = image
                })
            }

            // Add the test view as a subview to the scrollview.
            scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
        }
    }


    func configurePageControl() {
        // Set the total pages to the page control.
        pageControl.numberOfPages = totalPages

        // Set the initial page.
        pageControl.currentPage = seguedCurrentImageIndex!
    }


    // MARK: UIScrollViewDelegate method implementation

    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        // Calculate the new page index depending on the content offset.
        let currentPage = floor(scrollView.contentOffset.x / UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width);

        // Set the new page index to the page control.
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
    }


    // MARK: IBAction method implementation

    @IBAction func changePage(sender: AnyObject) {
        // Calculate the frame that should scroll to based on the page control current page.
        var newFrame = scrollView.frame
        newFrame.origin.x = newFrame.size.width * CGFloat(pageControl.currentPage)
        scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(newFrame, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a way out, I can use scroll paging to achieve the desired result, here's the code I used to go to a particular page of the scrollview:

```
var frame: CGRect = scrollView.frame
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(seguedCurrentImageIndex!)
frame.origin.y = 0
scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: false)
```